# Bad Request is not firing OnActionExecuted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, actionfilterattribute

When I am trying to send bad request through postman by bad request it's not firing `OnActionExecuted` method but when I send request good request means valid URL. It's firing the `OnActionExecuted`. I am bit confused why its not firing when bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Because OnActionExecuted is called after action method is executed. It gives you access to results produced by the action.

When you provide non-valid url that means no action is executed as action was not even found.

Comment: Even OnActionExecuting method also not firing